# Mark first non-zero element in each column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe, containing probabilities.

I also have a series, which are thresholds.

I want a resulting DF that has at most one 1 in every column, which would be the element where the column probabilities were lower than the corresponding series prob for the first time.

I.e. if I have a DF

```
A      B    C
0.1   0.7   0.01
0.3   0.05  0.9
0.01  0.01  0.02
```

and the series with values 0.02, 0.06, 0.1
Then I'd want output like

```
A    B    C
0    0    1
0    1    0
1    0    0
```

I can get something like

```
A    B    C
0    0    1
0    1    0
1    1    1
```

fairly easily, but I need it to have only the first elements, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting):

Given Series of Thresholds:

```
threshold = pd.Series([0.02, 0.06, 0.1])
```

```
m = df < threshold.values[:, None]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    m & (m.index.values[:, None] == m.idxmax().values),
    columns=df.columns,
    dtype=int
)
```

```
   A  B  C
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
```

---

Explaination:

Find where values are less than the array values:

```
df < threshold.values[:, None]
```

```
       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1  False   True  False
2   True   True   True
```

Then use `idxmax` to get the first instance of true per column:

```
m.idxmax()
```

```
A    2
B    1
C    0
dtype: int64
```

Then broadcast again to find where value is both `True` and max index for the column:

```
m & (m.index.values[:, None] == m.idxmax().values)
```

```
[[False False  True]
 [False  True False]
 [ True False False]]
```

Lastly turn back into a DataFrame:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    m & (m.index.values[:, None] == m.idxmax().values),
    columns=df.columns,
    dtype=int
)
```

```
   A  B  C
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks.  The idmax broadcasting step was what I was missing,